# google cache grabber

Tags: google, cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover a website from google cache?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18881/how-to-recover-a-website-from-google-cache)

Does anyone know a script to grab all contents of a site from google cache?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Did you lose your website?

Comment: Yes. But why is this important to answer the question?

Comment: Because we don't want to facilitate the stealing of content if we can help it

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Warrick](http://warrick.cs.odu.edu/warrick.html). It actually uses a few sources besides Google's cache as well, though you can limit that if you want.