# How to recover a website from google cache?

Tags: google, tools

My host provider told me last night their server crashed and they had restored the website from from an image they had from months ago, They told me this is the only backup they have. I also have no backup, as my backup server crashed few days ago.

Through google cache I can see all the website as it was few days ago. Is it possible to recover my website using google cache or is there any tool which help me to recover?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean google cache? Save as HTML would get you somewhere

Answer (score 4):

[Warrick](http://warrick.cs.odu.edu/warrick.html) will scrape the Google cache, as well as a few other sources, to try and recover lost site content.

Comment: Warrick is a great tool. If you don't want to fiddle with scripting, you can also try http://recovermywebsite.com

Answer (score 2):

I've downloaded my website's archived version from archive.org using Web Archive Downloader http://www.webarchivedownloader.com/

If your URLs contain sympols like ? and &, try this little PHP script, it will emulate URLs: http://recoverwebsite.com/node/7

Answer (score 0):

try doing a search in google, for example [this one](http://www.google.com/search?q=recovering+from+google+cache), it seems number of people have had tried the same thing, learn from their stories.