# Retrieving website

Tags: blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover a website from google cache?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18881/how-to-recover-a-website-from-google-cache)

Does anyone know of reliable websites (Warrick is currently closed for new requests) or programs (Mac-compatible) where I can retrieve a website that was deleted? I wasn't informed by my blog's host that my website was deleted because hosting services was terminated by the company. Since I have 2 years worth of posts at the website, I was wondering if it would be possible to retrieve them. I was using Wordpress.org for my website.

Comment: I think your comment would make a good answer.

Comment: I think I'll try it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you took a back up there will be no easy way to do this.

A long shot would be to check if the website was captured at [the internet archive](http://archive.org), although results will vary depending on your robots.txt amongst other factors. Unfortunately the best you'd get out of this is the post content - which you'd have to copy and paste manually :/

Your best bet IMHO is to contact your hosting provider and ask for database dumps. Once you have this you will be able to start a fresh WordPress install and drop the database in from phpMyAdmin (or some other tool). This is really the only way to get a worth-while backup of your site.

Answer (score 1):

Contact your web host if at all possible!

Do you have a Google sitemap? If you had Google create a sitemap of your WordPress blog, Google may have your web site cached in search results. If Google has cached your entire site you are lucky. Download your sitemap from Google and try searching for each page, when you do, if the site has been cached on Google you will see the 'cached' link below your old link, click this. This may help you get your content back but it is contingent upon many factors. If this will work, it will take some time to retrieve your site. Sorry for your loss!