# How to see previous look and feel from cached versions of a hacked website?

Tags: google-search-console, background-image, google-cache, domain-hacks, disaster-recovery

The main problem is I have no previous design samples like JPG or PSD files by which the site can be sliced again. So, I need the previous look and feel of the site before hacking. Otherwise, as I have no backup, if I know how to recover background image files for this hacked website, then it will be also fine.

I have killed whole my day to search for a solution whether there is a way to recover my theme files, specially the background image files which were used by the CSS files.

I've tried online cache solutions so far but with no luck.

For example, the following link is showing only my CSS file but I can not recover my image files. 
http://web.archive.org/web/20141019170905/http://www.drinkfreshlysqueezed.com/wp-content/themes/manifest_v1.1/style.css

I have also used: http://www.viewcached.com/ but it is same.

If I use Google cache link: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.drinkfreshlysqueezed.com then it shows me the hacked site for now (though this is not a problem as it will stay few more days until I fix and update my site!).

The solutions described into the following links are not working for me :(

[How to recover a website from google cache?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18881/how-to-recover-a-website-from-google-cache)

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/15633/how-to-modify-a-url-to-get-a-google-cached-version-of-page

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27414/how-to-use-googles-web-cache-to-view-a-page

Comment: There are only so many options available.

Comment: Hindsite is 100%, but nothing is as easy as recovering from proper system backups.